# Auth0 database and social connections, unique email addresses

Tags: auth0

Maybe I am missing something here, or this is a flaw in Auth0? I'll give an example of my issue:

Let's say I have my `Default App` (**client**), hooked up to that I have `Username-Password-Authentication` (**database connection**) and `google-oauth2` (**social connection**).

A user comes to my site, signs up via `google-oauth2` (**social connection**) using **joe@gmail.com**. Once complete, he gets added to my users in Auth0, all great.

A few months later, Joe comes back to my site, and being a busy guy, he forgets he signed up to my site before. This time, he decides to sign up using my custom Email and Password form, that will add the user to the `Username-Password-Authentication` (**database connection**). so he signs up there using **joe@gmail.com** again, and everything goes well, he is now listed in my user's section in my Auth0 dashboard.

This is the problem, I now have two **joe@gmail.com** accounts, one with `google-outh2` and one with `Username-Password-Authentication`. I really can't have this, I need a unique email address, regardless of the ID Auth0 supplies.

Does anyone know how I can make email address in my user section 100% unique? I'd think a rule would do this, but it appears rules only apply AFTER a user has been registered, so I can't run a rule before adding?

the only way I can see doing this right now is make my own checks and delete via the management API, but that is a really long and messy way to do it I feel.

Any help will be appreciated here!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Auth0's default behavior is to create a new account in the database for every unique entry. Since the user created using Google has a unique id (based on google-oauth2), and the user created using the sign-up form has a unique id - they will technically be considered two separate accounts. In order to resolve this disparity, you can establish a means with which the account data can be merged. In the documentation linked provided above, there are examples of three possible ways of doing this:

1. [Automatic Linking](https://auth0.com/docs/users/concepts/overview-user-account-linking#automatic-account-linking) - which involves creating a specific [rule](https://auth0.com/docs/rules) to merge users based on matching emails
2. [User-Initiated Linking](https://auth0.com/docs/users/concepts/overview-user-account-linking#user-initiated-account-linking) - which involves providing a UI for users to opt into merging users with matching emails
3. [Suggested Account Linking](https://auth0.com/docs/users/concepts/overview-user-account-linking#suggested-account-linking) - which involves setting up a rule that is linked into the UI

One important thing to consider is that the data returned from different social identity providers may not be normalized the way that data is normalized onto the `Username-Password-Database`. For example, while auth0's default for emails is to lowercase the information, `google-oauth2` may return emails as Uppercased - creating the potential for non-matching emails when checks are made using strict equality

Answer (score 0):

The option you are looking for is called **account linking**.
You can find more info at https://auth0.com/docs/link-accounts

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers. Either post a specific answer here, or just post the link as a comment to the question.